# Volume of surface Revolution by area bounded by $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=0$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, volume

The revolution across the y-axis, and the bounded area is between $y=\sin(x)$, and $y=0$ for ${0\le x \le \pi}$.

I did:
$$V_{shells}= 2 \pi \int_\limits{0}^\pi x\sin(x)dx=2\pi^2$$
I am trying to do this via slicing:
$$V_{slicing}=\pi \int_\limits{0}^1 \arcsin(y)dy$$
I end up getting:
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}-1$$
and times two the answer doesn't even mirror the first.

Comment: Your $V_{slicing}$ is not right, for two reasons. When integrating by slices, each disk of radius $x$ has volume $\pi x^2\,dy$. And you did not have the right radius $x$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function $y = \sin x$ in the range $0\le x \le \pi$, the image is $0\le y \le 1$. For such given $y$, there are up to two $x$'s that satisfies $y=\sin x$:

$$\begin{align*}
y &= \sin x\\
x &= n\pi + (-1)^n\arcsin y\\
 &= \arcsin y \quad \text{ or }\quad \pi - \arcsin y
\end{align*}$$

For disk integration, each slice is a "washer" or a cylinder with a hole. The outer radius is $(\pi - \arcsin y)$ and the inner radius of the hole is $\arcsin y$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{slicing} &= \int_0^1\pi\left[\left(\pi - \arcsin y\right)^2 - \left(\arcsin y\right)^2\right]dy\\
&= \int _0^1 \pi\left(\pi^2 - 2\pi\arcsin y\right)dy\\
&= \pi^2 \int _0^1 \left(\pi - 2\arcsin y\right)dy\\
&= \pi^2\left[\pi y -2y\arcsin y-2\sqrt{1-y^2}\right]_0^1\\
&= \pi^2\left[\left(\pi - 2\cdot\frac\pi2\right) - \left(-2\sqrt{1-0^2}\right)\right]\\
&= 2\pi^2
\end{align*}$$